# Ampps window is greyed out, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, localhost, ampps

I just installed Ampps through the terminal on Ubuntu 18.04, and everything went fine. When I run the program, however, the screen is completely greyed out, and I receive the following stack trace whenever I move the window:

```
[Ampps::exec] "/usr/local/ampps/apache/bin/httpd-k start" 
X Error: BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied) 10
  Extension:    130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode: 1 (X_ShmAttach)
  Resource id:  0x14a
X Error: BadShmSeg (invalid shared segment parameter) 128
  Extension:    130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode: 5 (X_ShmCreatePixmap)
  Resource id:  0x1c00010
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x1c00011
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x1c00011
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x1c00011
```

I've tried googling and searching on here, but couldn't find a solution. I read somewhere that I should use the command:

```
sudo QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 usr/local/ampps/Ampps.run
```

When I use it, it doesn't recognize as a `sudo` command, and says the command wasn't found.

Any help/answers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a slight mistake in your sentence. It should read:

sudo QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 /usr/local/ampps/Ampps

Answer (score 0):

For me setting the QT env to "native" did the trick:

> The Qt rendering speed is affected strongly by the rendering mode
>   used.  In Qt version 4.7 or newer this can be controlled by the
>   environmental  variable QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM. The options are "native",
>   "raster", or  "opengl" in order of increasing rendering speed. For
>   earlier versions of  Qt the terminal defaults to "raster".

```
export QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM=native
```